# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n+y_n|$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n|$ both converge, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n+y_n|$ also converge?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of the triangular inequality ?

Comment: Since $\sum_{n=1}^{N}|x_n| + \sum_{n=1}^{N}|y_n| \ge \sum_{n=1}^{N}|x_n+y_n|$, the result should follow in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i+y_i|$ and $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ and $Y_n= \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|$.

Since, for each $i\in\mathbb N$, $|x_i+y_i|\leq|x_i|+|y_i|$, we have that $S_n\leq X_n + Y_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

What can we conclude?

Comment: The comparison test, thanks! How about when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n|^2$ converges and we want to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n+y_n|^2$ converges? For this I think $|x_n+y_n|^2\geq |x_n|^2 + |y_n|^2$

Comment: @orianna_www $|x_n+y_n|^2=|x_n^2+2x_ny_n+y_n^2|=|x_n^2+y_n^2+2x_ny_n|\le|x_n|^2+|y_n|^2+|2x_ny_n|=|x_n|^2+|y_n|^2+2|x_n||y_n|$ and now you just need to show that $2|x_n||y_n|$ converge

Answer (score 1):

$|x_n+y_n|^2=x_n^2+y_n^2+2x_ny_n\ \leq2(x_n^2+y_n^2).$

now apply the comparison test ,since $ \sum x_n^2+y_n^2$ is convergent

this is to answer your question you asked in comment below

Answer (score 0):

It is quite clear , you can just use the triangle's inequality and then the comparison test to prove your result.